Jmeter 5.5 command line cannot overwrite the HTML output path
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l ./log/test.log  -e -o c:/htmlfolder

The HTML output is always going to jmeter \bin\report-output
Error generating the report: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot write to 'C:\jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\report-output' as folder is not empty
... end of run

reportgenerator.properties is default, nothing is changed
> # Sets the destination directory for generated html pages.
> # This will be overridden by the command line option -o
> #jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.property.output_dir=report-output
> ...
> # JSON Export that generates statistics.json
> 
> jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.json.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter
> #jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.json.property.output_dir=report-output


If you want to get brand new results into a folder where previous results are - provide -f command-line argument as well.
As per Full list of command-line options
-f, --forceDeleteResultFile
        force delete existing results files and web report folder if present before starting the test


P.S. According to JMeter Best Practices you should always use the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to JMeter 5.6 (or whatever is the latest version available at JMeter Downloads page) on next available opportunity

I did try -f , but still no luck, thanks
